# when I post ,it shows error of 404 not found in spring boot even when I have declared @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have made a userservice where I want to add new user, find user by id and also by other attributes. I have extended JPA repository since I learned that there is already functions. But I can't even save a new user.

This is my model

```
package bt.gov.dit.userservice.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long Id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String role;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String email, String role) {
        Id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

This is my repository

```
 package bt.gov.dit.userservice.dao;

import bt.gov.dit.userservice.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

    User findUserByRole(String role);

}
```

This is my service

```
package bt.gov.dit.userservice.service;
import bt.gov.dit.userservice.dao.UserRepository;
import bt.gov.dit.userservice.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User save(User user){

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
 public User getByRole(String role){
        return userRepository.findUserByRole(role);
    }
}
```

And this is my Controller

```
package bt.gov.dit.userservice.controller;

import bt.gov.dit.userservice.model.User;
//import bt.gov.dit.userservice.service.UserService;
import bt.gov.dit.userservice.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")

public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> create(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {

        User updated = userService.create(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(updated, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @GetMapping("/{role_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByRole(@PathVariable("role_id") String role)
    {
        User entity = userService.getByRole(role);

        return new ResponseEntity<User>(entity, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have just started learning Spring boot and I can't seem to understand what is wrong in code. I want to insert/save new user. But when I call /api/user it says 404 not found. I am using h2 in-memory db.

Comment: You provided your `@Service` twice instead of your controller. Please provide your controller, it is the most relevant code for your problem.

Comment: @StavShamir sir, I have added my controller. I am also trying to get a user by role. For example if I want admins, I want to Get all users with admin role. I have added code for that too but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the controller method argument name - role->role_id

```
   @GetMapping("/{role_id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByRole(@PathVariable("role_id") String role_id)
{
    User entity = userService.getByRole(role_id);

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(entity, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the role_id should be same as you mentioned in the routes.
Route example->localhost:8080/api/2

Answer (score 0):

you need to map the other part of the request like this:

@PostMapping(value="/user", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )

I also recommend you to use Springfox Swagger UI using the annotation @EnableSwagger2
This will provide you an user interface with all requests at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Link:
https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Sir, save has started working without adding the mapping . Could you please let me know on how to find a user by their role  . I have edited my code but it shows error

Comment: Maybe you need to modify to:  @GetMapping(value = "/{role_id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )

Comment: What is your error? Remember that the endpoint of your GET code points to /api/{role_id}

Comment: Also, below the @Entity try putting the name of the table with @Table(name="mytable")

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/role_id?role_id="menlam" this is what I used to look for role_id with menlam. it returns []

Comment: I am using in-memory database and i suppose, @Table(name="mytable") isn't required for that?

Comment: Your request according to your code should be http://localhost:8080/api/menlam

Comment: That is because a @ PathVariable is different than a @ RequestParam